# How to specify Cordova build target in build.json

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I'm having an error when I execute `cordova build`.

> xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
>
> ```
>   { platform:iOS Simulator, OS:latest, name:iPhone 11 Pro Max }
> ```

Since my app only builds on iPad, I think I need to set a build target to an iPad, but I'm not sure how to do this.

**Versions**

- XCode: Version 11.1 (11A1027)
- Cordova: cordova@9.0.0
- MacOS: 10.15 Catalina

My config.xml has these tags to specify iPad only:

```
    <preference name="target-device" value="tablet" />
    <preference name="deployment-target" value="10.3" />
```

The full error:

```
Reading build config file:
No simulator found for ". Falling back to the default target.
Building for "iPhone 11 Pro Max" Simulator (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-11-Pro-Max, iPhone-11-Pro-Max).
Building project: /Users/lucaban/.ghq/github.com/mesqueeb/sokketsu/src-cordova/platforms/ios/Sokketsu.xcworkspace
    Configuration: Debug
    Platform: emulator
    Target: iPhone 11 Pro Max
Running command: xcodebuild -workspace Sokketsu.xcworkspace -scheme Sokketsu -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -destination platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 11 Pro Max build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/lucaban/.ghq/github.com/mesqueeb/sokketsu/src-cordova/platforms/ios/build/emulator SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/lucaban/.ghq/github.com/mesqueeb/sokketsu/src-cordova/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
Build settings from command line:
    CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = /Users/lucaban/.ghq/github.com/mesqueeb/sokketsu/src-cordova/platforms/ios/build/emulator
    SDKROOT = iphonesimulator13.1
    SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR = /Users/lucaban/.ghq/github.com/mesqueeb/sokketsu/src-cordova/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch

xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
        { platform:iOS Simulator, OS:latest, name:iPhone 11 Pro Max }

    Available destinations for the "Sokketsu" scheme:
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:B90FC025-F8EB-40B3-90C5-E9094C0FFD17, OS:13.1, name:iPad Air (3rd generation) }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:3131A6AD-3C4E-4CEA-8889-9C7E22EAF816, OS:13.1, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:A8055BC4-F95C-43FA-8B28-7FACBD3D57B6, OS:13.1, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:7FAD7B1C-70DD-407A-AC99-3ACAD2670726, OS:13.1, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (3rd generation) }

    Ineligible destinations for the "Sokketsu" scheme:
        { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Generic iOS Device }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Generic iOS Simulator Device }
xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 70
```

Comment: I'm running into the same issue and can't find any documentation that clearly explains how this should be handled. Cordova's documentation looks like it's in need of an update.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the `target-device` to `universal` and then change it back to tablet in Xcode when finished.

config.xml

```
<preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
```

PS: This issue started probably around cordova-ios version 5.0.1 when running cordova build ios command.

Comment: This is a temporary workaround, not a fix.

Answer (score 4):

You can solve this issue by sending the device name as a `buildFlag`

If you are using **cordova** use below command

```
cordova build ios --buildFlag="-destination platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPad Pro (11-inch)"
```

For me, I was using this in an **Ionic** project.

```
ionic cordova build ios -- --buildFlag="-destination platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPad Pro (11-inch)"
```

You can choose any device name you want from the list **Available destinations** listed in your error

Comment: Thanks! This one did it for me 

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in terminal it says:
xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:

{ platform:iOS Simulator, OS:latest, name:iPhone 11 Pro Max }

You can follow below steps:

1. Go to Xcode
2. Under simulator target click 'Add Additional Simulators'

   [image]
3. Once this screen pops up, click on + icon on bottom left corner
   [image]
4. It will display a screen to add new simulator: Add the one for which your build is failing , in this case:iPhone 11 Pro Max, Select Device type as(iPhone 11 Pro Max) and latest OS version.
   [image]
5. Go to terminal and try build command again.